# Linux Needs a Password but Password doesn't work

Tags: sudo, password

First off I need to say I'm almost a noob at this - as in I didn't know what Linux was a few weeks ago, I've learnt a lot myself but I need some help if poss please.

I'm using a Chromebook, Debian 10. To download software it's asking for a password that I havnt set. I've messed about a lot lately to get Roblox Studio (with Grapejuice) and Blender and have never been asked for a password until now - this is while trying to get the newer Blender 2.82 following this https://chromeunboxed.com/three-ways-to-install-blender-3d-software-on-your-chromebook/

I had debugging on, reset password in Linux and also thro Crosh.  I read having debugging on could be causing my problem so I powerwashed the Chromebook, started afresh this time with it off. Installed Linux, created a new username but again no password.

Still the same problem.

I did this:

```
sudo su root
passwd
```

Created a new one that it said was verified but again, when it asks for password to install it says it failed.

Ive spent hours looking into this and trying anything I can find that might help, I just don't know what else to do.

If anyone has any ideas that could help me please I would be very grateful.

Comment: Welcome to Linux and StackExchange. :) Your description of your problem is hard to follow. Why do you want to create a new user? That is not necessary and I don't think it is supported. Also please take a closer look, are you really in Linux or in a different shell like vmc? (You have no permissions there.) What does `cat /etc/os-release` say? Powerwashing or removing Crostini Linux Apps should give a completely new environment after you set it up again. Be careful ChromeOS 83 might break flatpak, at least it did on my Ubuntu 20.04 Crostini Container. You should not make a lot of modifications

Answer (score 2):

Are you installing using root as well? I ask because when you do `sudo passwd`, it changes the password of the root user. Thus, if your installing with a non-root user, it expects the users password, not root.

Comment: And if he's installing as root, there's no point in using sudo.

Comment: Your statement is true but it does not answer the question entirely. Also in Crostini sudoers in configured to not ask for a password. I think the question itself needs improvement and more clarity to be answered, until then we can only make comments. There is also a chat here on this site where people can hang out and solve problems that do not fit the Q&A format.

Comment: Justahuman thank you!! I was not using root, I tried this before when debugging was on, I don't know why I didn't try afterwards. I think my brain has been slightly overloaded by it all. I now have Blender 2.82 on my Chromebook. Yes everyone, my question wasn't easy to follow, again, I'm a noob. I do have one other problem that has only occured since powerwash. I have the terminal open, copying and pasting command lines from browser. But now if I go to browser the terminal goes white&blank, same vice versa.I don't suppose you would know why this is happening?Thank you for all your replies guys